# FFMPEG Audio Issues Youtube Live

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-livestreaming-api

This issue may have more to do with youtube than ffmpeg, but hopefully someone can help anyway.

I am having the exact issue described in this post https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/nHTb7ilKvrw. I would have added to it, but it is locked for some reason.

I create a stream from a local webm file on my computer using ffmpeg. This file sounds perfectly fine, and still sounds fine when it is sent to platforms other than youtube live (twitch/facebook). On youtube live, however, the audio has static and crackles during the live feed, but the archive of the video on youtube (after processing) sounds perfectly fine. The ffmpeg command is

`ffmpeg -re -i test.webm -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/${your_key}`

Webm files from this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/2rgv7pgj/) will have the issue.

If someone could offer advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the issue reproducible using any other mp4, webm or other files?

Comment: Any file created using the fiddle that I linked (webm or otherwise) have the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this on the client side using the `DynamicsCompressorNode` in the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DynamicsCompressorNode). For some reason the audio was clipping on youtube exclusively. This filter stopped the clipping and fixed the poor quality on youtube.